vs-code is lacking indentation for only .sass and not converting the .sass file into .css , giving comment /*# sourceMappingURL=stlyles.css.map */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stlyles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>please find a solution to my problem i am struggling from the whole day and my typing speed is 40wpm</h1>
    
</body>
</html>

this was not giving the indentation and[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/O9s9dAt1.png)ntation in the .sass file      *and it is not converting the .sass file in the .css file *

in this indentation is not coming on .sass file only above is my html code
